# recursive tree-like parsing with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following input & output data (Sheet1 from 1-19, Sheet2 from 21+,  followed by output)
https://ethercalc.org/bzrwyz8bsail (Note that the children are aligned to the right instead of having 2 spaces which is the formatting the script does)

I have the following VBA script which parses the parents and items and writes to Sheet 2:

```
Sub newlist()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Dim Ide As String
    Dim k As Long
    Dim kk As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim entity As String

    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    w2.Cells(1, 1).Value = w1.Cells(1, 8).Value
    w2.Cells(1, 2).Value = w1.Cells(1, 10).Value
    c = 0
    Ide = Cells(1, 1).Value
    w1.Activate
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    k = 3
    kk = 1
    For i = 2 To n
        If w1.Cells(i, 8).Value = Ide Then
            entity= w1.Cells(i, 10).Value
            entityString = "  " & entity
            w2.Cells(kk + 1, 1).Value = entityString
            kk = kk + 1
            k = k + 1
        Else
            kk = kk + 1
            k = 3
            Ide = w1.Cells(i, 8).Value
            entity= w1.Cells(i, 10).Value
            w2.Cells(kk, 1).Value = Ide
            kk = kk + 1
            entityString = "  " & entity
            w2.Cells(kk, 1).Value = entityString
        End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

As one can see in the output, parents that are a child themselves are not written under their parent. For instance, the first Papa's children should be written under Root's child Papa, and no name should be repeated twice. Another instance is how Echo's children should be under Echo, rather than being repeated.

How would I go about handling this using recursion? It seems like iteration is not effective.

Comment: Yes recursion is possible in VBA.

Comment: @QHarr I'm not sure how to implement it to solve my problem, I don't even know if recursion could be used to do what I'm doing

Comment: Also, you should get in the habit of declaring your variables. You've declared none of them in this code, which makes it very difficult to follow the code, and also is inefficient, and often leads to type mismatch errors due to implicit casting.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm not used to VBA, do you mean just assigning names to some of the cell values I use?

Comment: No, I mean *declaring variables* by name and type, e.g., `Dim k as Long` and `Dim w1 as Worksheet`, etc. Undeclared variables are the devil's handiwork.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx

Comment: @DavidZemens I didn't realize VBA could have these kind of technicalities, thanks for the suggestion I'll update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *really* weak about recursion, but here's a go at it. Output below is from the `Debug.Print` statement:

```
Root
  Lima
    Delta
    Echo
      Foxtrot
      Golf
      Hotel
      India
      Juliett
      Kilo
  Mike
  November
  Oscar
    Papa
      Alpha
      Bravo
      Charlie
    Quebec
```

And the output on Sheet 2 with the indent levels:

[image]

Recursion happens when the method `ProcessItem` calls itself within the `For Each v In dict(name)` loop:

```
Option Explicit
Sub newlist()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim num_rows
    Dim parent As Range, parentName As String
    Dim parentRange As Range, childrenRange As Range
    Dim childCount As Long
    Dim p As Variant

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet6")
    num_rows = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    'If there's no parentName column, we can't continue.
    If w1.Rows(1).Find("parentName") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set parentRange = w1.Rows(1).Find("parentName").Offset(1).Resize(num_rows - 1, 1)
    'If there's no Root level, how do we know where to start?
    If parentRange.Find("Root") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each parent In parentRange
        If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
            Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
            dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
        End If
    Next
    Set w2 = Sheets.Add
    ' Recursive method to traverse our dictionary, beginning at Root element.
    Call ProcessItem("Root", dict, w2, 2)

    w2.Cells(1, 1).Value = w1.Cells(1, 8).Value
    w2.Cells(1, 2).Value = w1.Cells(1, 10).Value

End Sub
Private Sub ProcessItem(name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
Dim output As String, v
' add spaces to indent the output string:
output = WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & name
Debug.Print output
' write output to the new worksheet:
ws.Cells(row_num, 1).Value = output
row_num = row_num + 1
If Not dict.Exists(name) Then
    'we're at a terminal element, a child with no children.
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each v In dict(name)
        ' ## RECURSION ##
        Call ProcessItem(CStr(v), dict, ws, row_num, indent + 2)
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

## Follow-up:

If you wanted to track the parent name also (ex. "parent.child") then I think you could do it like this (untested):

Make your initial call like so -- you don't actually need to name the argument in the function call, but I notated it like this just to illustrate:

```
Call ProcessItem(parentName:="", "Root", dict, w2, 2)
```

Then the function needs to be modified slightly:

```
Private Sub ProcessItem(parentName as String, name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
Dim output As String, v
output = IIF(parentName = "", name, parentName & "." & name)
output = WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & output
Debug.Print output
' write output to the new worksheet:
ws.Cells(row_num, 1).Value = output
row_num = row_num + 1
If Not dict.Exists(name) Then
    'we're at a terminal element, a child with no children.
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each v In dict(name)
        ' ## RECURSION ##
        Call ProcessItem(name, CStr(v), dict, ws, row_num, indent + 2)
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I didn't think using a recursive helper function was even possible. Also, I wasn't aware that you could refer to a column by name rather than index. Out of curiosity, how would the Find command handle a sheet that has 2 of the same column names, or how would you handle it from the code?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois `Find` would return the first matching column.

Comment: Also, important distinction: we're not referring to column by name, we're using the `Find` method to search for a cell which contains a particular value. Then we are defining a range of cells based on that.

Comment: Thanks! As a followup question, if I wanted to perform the same exercise using parentID and entityID as opposed to names, would I simply replace "parentName" with "parentID" and "Root" with "-220"?

Comment: There is no `entityId` column, and there is no value of `-220` in the `parentId` column, so, no, that does not appear to be correct.

Comment: There's also an assumption that parent/child are 2 columns apart (e.g., Column I and column K). So as long as your columns have the same offset, and as long as you're using valid column name and values, I think it would work.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot I modified the data to be simpler - "-220" is my actual constant ID for roots, and entityID is synonymous with itemID. Naming aside, it seems like even when the 2 column offset is maintained, replacing the root with another constant string ("-220") and "parentName" with "parentID" doesn't write anything after the first -220. Is there something else that should be changed?

Comment: only one way to find out for sure, run it and see if it errors :)  But it seems like it ought to work as long as you maintain the 2-column offset.

Comment: @DavidZemens, a nice and instructive solution +. **Amplifying remark**: If the `Set childrenRange` statement counts only *one cell*, this child item can't be listed. Workaround with a temporary array (`Dim temp`) thereafter to avoid issues: `If childCount = 1 Then` followed by `ReDim temp(1 To 1, 1 To 1): temp(1, 1) = childrenRange.Value` and a special add by `dict.Add parent.Value, temp` before a final `Else` adding the child items to dictionary via the double transposition you showed already.

Comment: Works perfectly for ID's! Followup question, if one wanted to track the parent name in the recursion on top of just "name", what is the logic that's needed in terms of the first call and the recursive calls?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois I added some example code for that, but have not tested it. If you have further problems implementing that, best to ask a new question :)

Comment: @DavidZemens my apologies for the late followup question, but it seems like my adjustment of this code seems to skip the first row in "WeightsDB", meaning one of my leafs is missing. I was wondering where in this code it specifies at what row the parsing starts, because I can't seem to find it no matter how hard I look.

Comment: Beg pardon, but I have no idea what "WeightsDB" is and this is the first time you've mentioned it, 10+ days after posing the last comment. I would guess, at this point, that it has to do with the `row_num` you're passing to the procedure. But I'm not sure, and I won't be able to debug. I suggest posing a *new question* if you need further assistance with this particular problem. Cheers.

Comment: Also possibly related, please refer to @T.M. comment above, which I did **not** implement in the code provided in the answer.